# am using ResNet18 for image classification and my dataset has 3 classes but it give me error in: trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=10, gpus=1)

Tags: google-colaboratory

am using ResNet18 for image classification and my dataset has 3 classes but it give me error in: trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=10, gpus=1)

Error is :TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 126>()
124 # Initialize and train the model
125 model = TomatoModel(num_classes=num_classes)
--> 126 trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=10, gpus=1)  # Adjust as needed
127
128 # Train the model

How to fix this error?